# Inserting xyz as pointcloud points

Tags: postgis, pgpointcloud

I'm trying to insert some xyz point data into a pc_point, I get the error `ERROR:  array dimensions do not match schema dimensions of pcid = 1`

running `SELECT PC_MakePoint(1, ARRAY[-127, 45, 124.0, 4.0]);` gives the same error. the pgpointcloud extension is working since I can get pointclouds in using pdal pipelines.

I'm trying to follow the example here http://s3.cleverelephant.ca/foss4gna2013-pointcloud.pdf

```
CREATE TABLE pointcloud_99_526.pcpoints (  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,  pt PcPoint(1) );
select * from pointcloud_99_526.pcpoints;

INSERT INTO pointcloud_99_526.pcpoints (pt)
SELECT PC_MakePoint(1, ARRAY[x,y,z,intensity])
FROM (
  SELECT
  -127+a/100.0 AS x,
    45+a/100.0 AS y,
         1.0*a AS z,
          a/10 AS intensity
  FROM generate_series(1,100) AS a
) AS values;
```

Comment: what's the `pcid 1` XML definition? without context, that error states that you define either more or less dimensions than the 4 you want

Comment: You should look at your .xml file schema definition and look in your pc_dimension. You must have 4 dimensions described here.

Comment: Where do I find the pcid xml file definition?

Comment: ok I found it in the pointcloud_columns table in the public schema, I needed 15 dimensions